# How to make a Splash Screen with a text at bottom?

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-splashscreen

I was checking some of Google's apps splash screens and I realized that some of them have an Icon (centered) and a text at the bottom.

[image]

The [Splash Screen API](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen) doc doesn't mention how one can do it and I didn't find anything related to it.

Is it possible to achieve it with the Splash Screen API? If not, what would be the recommended way to create a custom Splash Screen that is shown as soon as the user touches the app's icon?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem by following the topic **Using a Launcher Theme** in this [post](https://proandroiddev.com/splash-screen-in-android-3bd9552b92a5) by Vinod Baste:

[image]

All in all, we can use the `android:windowBackground` attribute in a custom theme to reference the splash screen background drawable.